# Next 14 Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, serverless, next.js13

I have just installed a nextjs project with `npx create-next-app@latest`.

**current versions**

```
"next": "14.1.3",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18",
"sharp": "^0.33.2"
```

**next.config.mjs**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

export default nextConfig;
```

My project is running perfectly fine locally in dev and after build.

But while deploying Nextjs Application on **AWS S3 bucket with serverless** I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build

> Build error occurred
Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js.
See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deprecated-target-config
```

As you can see I don't have any target property on my `next.config.mjs` file still I am getting this error. I also tried `output: "standalone"` but got no success.

I can see people facing same error in stack overflow but most of the issue is related to AWS Amplify. I am using **AWS S3 bucket with serverless**.

**Note**: I have 3 Nextjs project deployed on AWS S3 with serverless with same configs only difference in this project is I am using Next version 14.1.3 here, rest all is Next version 12.0.8.

I don't know if this will help but here is my **serverless.yml** file below

```
NEXT-TEST:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@3.6.0"  
  inputs:
    runtime:
      defaultLambda: "nodejs18.x"
      apiLambda: "nodejs18.x"
      imageLambda: "nodejs18.x"
    memory:
      defaultLambda: 4096
      apiLambda: 4096
      imageLambda: 4096
    timeout:
      defaultLambda: 30
      apiLambda: 30
      imageLambda: 30
  
    bucketRegion: XXXXX
    bucketName: XXXXXX
```

To deploy I am using below command:
`npx serverless@2.72.2`

I have searched and tried many different solution but nothing worked for me.

Please Help!